# Wordpress - don't show Lightbox on home page. (prototype jquery problem)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress with Smooth Gallery for showing featured  news slider,
and i want to use a Lightbox 2 but when the later is loaded the Smooth Gallery is broken
becouse of the prototype jquery conflict.

How to make Lightbox not show itself at home page?
(Slider is only on home page)
I tried to change

```
if (!is_admin()) {
wp_enqueue_script('lightbox', ($stimuli_lightbox_plugin_prefix.$stimuli_lightbox_js),array('scriptaculous-effects'), '1.8');
}
```

to

```
if (!is_admin() and !is_home()) { ...
```

but it still includes prototype on home page.
What i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both Pat and TheDeadMedic, problem was still with && !is_home and  && !is_fornt_page.

I dont know why but in place where i tried is_home and is_front_page wasn't doing its job,
but i found on other page that wraping whole wp_enqueue_script in a function is doing it. So its like this:

```
function scripts() {
if (!is_admin() && !is_home() ) {
// jquery
global $stimuli_lightbox_plugin_prefix;
global $stimuli_lightbox_js;
wp_enqueue_script('lightbox',     ($stimuli_lightbox_plugin_prefix.$stimuli_lightbox_js), array('scriptaculous-effects'), '1.8');

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'scripts'); // now just run the function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!is_admin() && !is_front_page())
    wp_enqueue_script('lightbox', ($stimuli_lightbox_plugin_prefix.$stimuli_lightbox_js),array('scriptaculous-effects'), '1.8');
```

Answer (score 1):

So close - what you've got should work, you just have the `and` syntax wrong in your `if` condition:

```
if (!is_admin() && !is_home()) { ....
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that syntax - PHP supports both logical and bitwise operators - the problem is you're most likely using a static front page (see my answer).